# How to print lines of text with date older than two days

Tags: awk

I have the following text file that I am working with and must be able to parse only the object name value when the `creationdatetime` is older than two days.

```
objectname ...........................: \Path\to\file\hpvss-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-29Aug12 22.39.15
creationdatetime .....................: 01-Sep-2012 02:17:43
objectname ...........................: \Path\to\file\hpVSS-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-28Aug12 22.16.19
creationdatetime .....................: 03-Sep-2012 10:18:09
objectname ...........................: \Path\to\file\hpVSS-LUN-22May-12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-27Aug12 22.01.52
creationdatetime .....................: 03-Sep-2012 10:18:33
```

An output of the command for the above would be:

```
\Path\to\file\hpvss-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-29Aug12 22.39.15
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Prem

Answer (score 3):

Date parsing in `awk` is a bit tricky but it can be done using `mktime`. To convert the month name to numeric, an associative translation array is defined.

The path names have space in them so the best choice for field separator is probably `:` (colon followed by space). Here's a working awk script:

**older_than_two_days.awk**

```
BEGIN {
  months2num["Jan"] = 1;  months2num["Feb"] =  2; months2num["Mar"] =  3; months2num["Apr"] =  4;
  months2num["May"] = 5;  months2num["Jun"] =  6; months2num["Jul"] =  7; months2num["Aug"] =  8;
  months2num["Sep"] = 9;  months2num["Oct"] = 10; months2num["Nov"] = 11; months2num["Dec"] = 12;

  now = systime()
  two_days = 2 * 24 * 3600
  FS  = ": "
}

$1 ~ /objectname/ { 
  path = $2
}

$1 ~ /creationdatetime/ {
  split($2, ds, " ")
  split(ds[1], d, "-")
  split(ds[2], t, ":")
  date           = d[3] " " months2num[d[2]] " " d[1] " " t[1] " " t[2] " " t[3]
  age_in_seconds = mktime(date)

  if(now - age_in_seconds > two_days)
    print path
}
```

All the splitting in the last block is to pick out the date bits and convert them into a format that `mktime` accepts.

Run it like this:

```
awk -f older_than_two_days.awk infile
```

Output:

```
\Path\to\file\hpvss-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-29Aug12 22.39.15
```

Comment: If the answer solves your question satisfactorily, consider voting it up and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in 2 phases:

1) reformat you input file

```
awk '/objectname/{$1=$2="";file=$0;getline;$1=$2="";print $0" |"file}' inputfile > inputfile2
```

This way you would deal with

```
01-Sep-2012 02:17:43 |  \Path\to\file\hpvss-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-29Aug12 22.39.15
03-Sep-2012 10:18:09 |  \Path\to\file\hpVSS-LUN-22May12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-28Aug12 22.16.19
03-Sep-2012 10:18:33 |  \Path\to\file\hpVSS-LUN-22May-12 22.24.11\hpVSS-LUN-27Aug12 22.01.52
```

2) filter on dates:

```
COMPARDATE=$(($(date +%s)-2*24*3600)) # 2 days off
IFS='|'
while read d f
do 
  [[ $(date -d "$d" +%s) < $COMPARDATE ]] && printf "%s\n" "$f"
done < inputfile2
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane! Is there any way to do the filtering in awk, as I am working in the windows environment using gawk?

Comment: If you intend to do serious test processing I suggest you install cygwin http://cygwin.com/ on your Windows machine. This way you will be able to script almost as easily as on a Unix machine